# Why my 2D list object cannot be subscriptable?

Tags: python, json, list, types, nonetype

I've downloaded data from this link:
(https://data.cesko.digital/obce/1/obce.json)
Data has been successfully stored in a dictionary and when I try to extract coordinates ('souradnice') it acts like NoneType object and doesn't allow me to do it using for loop. However if I try to print only one coordinate, it gives me no error. Where did I make a mistake?

```
url = 'https://data.cesko.digital/obce/1/obce.json'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
location_data = resp.json()
type(location_data)
x = list()
y = list()
for z in range(len(cz)):
    y.append(cz[z][0])
    x.append(cz[z][1])
```

[image]

I tried to find the information on forums, tried to convert coordinate data into a np.array but nothing seems to help.

Comment: What is `cz`?  It contains at least one None value (thus the error), but you didn't show us where this variable came from.

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]. You are omitting what `cz` is, which is totally crucial. Indeed, everything is crucial.

Comment: 'cz = []
    for x in range(location_data['itemCount']):
        cz.append(location_data['municipalities'][x]['souradnice'])'

Answer (score 1):

Some municipalities contain `None` in their "souradnice" key so you have to check for that:

```py
import requests

url = "https://data.cesko.digital/obce/1/obce.json"

data = requests.get(url).json()

for m in data['municipalities']:
    # some municipalities contain 'null' in "souradnice" key
    # for example "Morkovice-Slížany"
    souradnice = m['souradnice']
    if souradnice is None:
        x, y = None, None
    else:
        x, y = souradnice
    print(m['hezkyNazev'], x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missing values in your dataset that causes the bug if they are not dealt with.

```
x = list()
y = list()

muncipalites=location_data['municipalities']

for z in range(len(muncipalites)):
    if isinstance(muncipalites[z]['souradnice'],list):
        y.append(muncipalites[z]['souradnice'][0])
        x.append(muncipalites[z]['souradnice'][1])
    else:
        print(f"missing data for {muncipalites[z][list(muncipalites[z].keys())[0]]}")
```